# Automake command from different directory

Tags: gnu, readonly, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have the folder/files **/sources/{configure.ac,Makefile.am,...}**

How can I execute *Automake* command so files/folder *configure*, *Makefile*, and *autom4te.cache* are not generated in **/sources** but in **/mydir** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The directory from which you run `configure` will be the root directory of where the generated files are put.

```
cd /mydir
/sources/configure
```

(Although beware; this is not as common as running `./configure` right in the source tree. You're supposed to account for it when writing a GNU-compliant `configure` script, but nonetheless some packages will not build this way.)

Comment: Automake doesn't create `configure`, `Makefile`, and `autom4te.cache`, so you can't influence that when running the `automake` command.